Is a Crew Dragon capsule really so "thin-skinned" that radiation specific to 1400 km can penetrate it?
Crew Dragon: How thick is the skin? currently has no answer (so I've bountied it). The beginning of Wikipedia's Polaris Dawn suggests that in the early, high apogee (~1,200 km) part of the mission:

They passed through parts of the Van Allen radiation belt to study the health effects of space radiation and spaceflight on the human body.

Well there are already plenty of studies on "health effects of...  spaceflight on the human body" so the specific passing through the Van Allen radiation belt would be, if anything, "to study the health effects of space radiation".
Van Allen belts form when there is a source of ionized atoms (primarily protons) and electrons and a magnetic field that can hold on to them for a while. Earth's field is a fraction of a gauss on the surface and in LEO, so this limits the energy of the protons and electrons that would be present in, and specific to, the lower Van Allen belt.
Question: Is Crew Dragon really so "thin-skinned" that protons and electrons that are trapped in (and specific to) the lower Van Allen belt can really penetrate it and reach the astronauts' bodies in a biologically meaningful way?
There are range tables for protons and electrons (in say aluminum) as a function of energy, and certainly the lower Van Allen belt's charged particle energy spectrum has been characterized; this shouldn't be hard to figure out one way or the other.
Not that the "space walks" (actually "space dunks" - no feet got wet) were not performed at this Van Allen belt exploring altitude. Unless I misunderstand, the capsule was closed and pressurized.

You say "certainly the lower Van Allen belt's charged particle energy spectrum has been characterized". Not really. First of all, the belts aren't the pretty things in in textbooks. They are quite dynamic and complicated. Even at ISS altitudes, modeling instrument background for things like NICER, MAXI, and AMS is difficult because of the heterogeneity and variability of the radiation environment.
It's even more complicated inside a spacecraft because the shielding makes more radiation through spallation, bremsstrahlung, pair production, ...
You may sample a bit of the complexity by reading Mauk et al., Science Objectives and Rationale for the Radiation Belt Storm Probes Mission,
September 2012, Space Science Reviews 179(1-4)
DOI:10.1007/s11214-012-9908-y. Here's an average particle spectrum from the article.


Fig. 2 (a) Proton radiation belt distribution from Sawyer and Vette (1976). The red profile added to this display corresponds to those protons (>20 MeV) that just penetrate about 100 mils (0.25 cm) aluminum. NASA publication. (b) Electron radiation belt figure generated by combining 2 of the standard plots provided in the Handbook of Geophysics and the Space Environment (edited by Jursa 1985), the right-hand portion generated by Singley and Vette (1972). The inner electron belt fluxes are more uncertain because it is difficult to measure energetic electrons in an environment of very energetic protons. The red profile corresponds to those electrons (>1.5 MeV) that just penetrate about 100 mils (0.25 cm) aluminum. Air Force publication

The red line represents particles that just penetrate 2.5 mm of aluminum. Maybe that's a bit thinner than the effective thickness of Dragon, but spacecraft are not well shielded: they have to be light. In any case, you can see that fluxes are still substantial at higher energies. And if you read the rest of the article, you should be a bit nervous about the notion that an average spectrum is predictive.
That said, I'd be surprised if there's much learned from this brief experiment. Still, I've been surprised before...

Wow, I was really surprised to see that 10 MeV protons and 0.5 MeV electrons could be found in the lower belt! One nit: "You say 'certainly the lower Van Allen belt's charged particle energy spectrum has been characterized'. Not really." To support your "Not really." you link to a 12 year old article published BEFORE the launch of the "NASA Radiation Belt Storm Probes (RBSP)" and show a plot of data mostly measured in the 1970's, 50 years ago. If you'd like to show that in 2024 the van Allen belts are still not characterized, please cite current sources...

... or at least the final analysis of the 2012 RBSP mission results

The radiation background on NICER is still incompletely understood after seven years of study. This work is ongoing, unpublished, and will never result in a particle spectrum, but existing models don't work terribly well.

NICER is only at ~400 km, Polaris Dawn did their "biological effects of radiation" experiment at 1200 km presumably because the several days at 700 km still wasn't getting high enough into the lower Van Allen belt. I don't see the relevance of NICER data to the Van Allen belt. However, I DO see the relevance of finding the final report for the RBSP mission, or something even more recent. Remember, my question asks about "radiation specific to 1400 km".

@uhoh NICER just tells us that even at lower, better studied altitudes, there is much ignorance. And the ISS does travel through parts of the inner Van Allen belt: the South Atlantic Anomaly and the polar horns.

@uhoh The NICER measurement chains saturate at a deposited energy of ~18 keV. But we should be able to take a model of the radiation environment and predict what NICER would see if the model was correct. Unfortunately, that doesn't work very well.

@uhoh The biological effects may be due to some funky, poorly studied component of the radiation at 1400 km. What's the flux of 1 GeV Fe nuclei up there?

I like the way you think :-)

@uhoh Chandra got burned by a funky, poorly studied low energy component of the outer belt. We figured out how to protect the CCDs before the damage was fatal, but it was a close thing.
